# Angular - Cancel previous search requests and keep only last

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a HTTP request

```
searchService() {
    return this.httpClient.get(URL);
}
```

And I'm subscribing like this

```
search() {
   this.service.searchService().subscribe((data) => { });
}
```

My problem is that it takes some seconds and if someone clicks multiple times with different search keys, the results depend on the speed of request.

So, I want to cancel all previous subscriptions and keep only the last search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use some few rxjs operators, namely `debounceTime`, `distinctUntilChanged` and `switchMap` to make sure you don’t send too many API calls and that you get only the results from the latest request.

Check this article for detailed example:
https://alligator.io/angular/real-time-search-angular-rxjs/

Answer (score 0):

Use [`debounceTime`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html) to achieve this

> **debounceTime**
>   **signature: debounceTime(dueTime: number, scheduler: Scheduler): Observable**

Example

```
// RxJS v6+
import { debounceTime} from 'rxjs/operators';
// ...
search() {
   this.service.searchService().pipe(debounceTime(500)).subscribe((data) => { });
}
```